# Hacer referencia al propio formulario con AJAX y JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema de formularios, la cosa es que genero diferentes formularios con la información de cada uno de los usuarios que tengo, lo hago de esta forma:

```
    <table id="inf-us-filt">
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($usuarios); $i++) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="img-pequenna"><img src="<?php echo $usuarios[$i]['foto_perfil'] ?>"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php echo $usuarios[$i]['nick'] ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $usuarios[$i]['nombre'] ?> <?php echo $usuarios[$i]['apellidos'] ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $usuarios[$i]['ciudad'] ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $usuarios[$i]['intereses'] ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $usuarios[$i]['edad'] ?> años</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="btns-filt">
                        <?php
                        if (!$usuarios[$i]["esFavorito"]) {
                        ?>
                            <div class="btn-fav">
                                <form name="prueba" id="formAnnadirFavorito" action="../conexiones/modDatos/cambiarFavorito.php" method="POST">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="idUsuario" name="idUsuario" value="<?php echo $usuarios[$i]['id'] ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="e" name="e" value="a">
                                    <button type="submit"><img class="btn-accion" src="../imgs/icons/favorito.png"></button>

                                </form>
                            </div>

                        <?php
                        } else {
                        ?>
                            <div class="btn-fav">
                                <button><img class="btn-accion" src="../imgs/icons/favorito-block.png"></button>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Este formulario sirve para añadir el perfil a favorito del usuario marcado. El problema me viene en el AJAX. Como tengo varios formularios con el mismo nombre e id (he probado con las dos formas), cuando intento ocultar el `button` para mostrar otro, se me cambia en todos. El código es el siguiente:

```
    $("form[name='prueba']").bind("submit", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $("form[name='prueba']").find('button[type="submit"]').hide();
                $("form[name='prueba']").append("<button><img class='btn-accion' src='../imgs/icons/favorito-block.png'></button>");
                alert("¡Añadido a favoritos con éxito!");

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ha habido un error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Lo pongo con `form[name='prueba']` debido a que si lo pongo con el ID, solo se me ejecuta bien el primer usuario que me sale, imagino que por ser problema del propio ID, no lo se.

Si por ejemplo pongo `$(this).find('button[type="submit"]').hide();` no me lo reconoce, entonces no se como hacer referencia al botón de submit del propio formulario.

Comment: Estás repitiendo nombre e ID de formularios. Creo que sería más fácil asignar una clase y usar `$('.nombre-de-clase').on('submit', function() {});`

Comment: No funciona, al crearse todos los usuarios con la misma clase, id, o nombre, se cambian todos.

Answer (score 0):

Después de estar estos días matandome la cabeza di con la solución, es muy sencilla. Tan solo hay que crear una variable fuera del ajax, pero dentro de la función, y usar esas variables dentro del ajax. No se por que motivo tiene que ser así, pero funciona, de tal forma que luego ya puedes usar la función `hide()` o lo que quieras. En mi caso al final reemplacé la imagen que contiene el botón y desabilité el mismo botón, de tal forma que el formulario correspondiente queda así:

```
<div class="btn-fav">
    <form name="formFavorito" id="formAnnadirFavorito" action="../conexiones/modDatos/cambiarFavorito.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="idUsuario" name="idUsuario" value="<?php echo $usuarios[$i]['id'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="e" name="e" value="a">
        <button type="submit"><img class="btn-accion" src="../imgs/icons/favorito.png"></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Mientras que el AJAX quedaría así:

```
$("form[name='formFavorito']").bind("submit", function () {
        var btn = $(this).find("button");
        var img = $(this).find("img");
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function () {
               btn.attr("disabled");
               img.attr("src", "../imgs/icons/favorito-block.png");
               alert("¡Añadido a favoritos con éxito!");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ha habido un error");
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```